# DROP TABLE not work in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, drop-table

I try to drop table programmatically nothing error show in logcat, but there has no any result :

Here my Database Helper class :

```
public class database1 extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static final String DB_Name="database";
    private static final int DB_Version=1;
    private static final String tbl_arrival1="arrival1";
    private static final String STRING_CREATE1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+tbl_arrival1
            +" (_f_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            +"f_date TEXT,"
            +"o_rder NUMERIC,"
            +"rem_com TEXT);";
    public database1 (Context ctx)
    {
        super(ctx,DB_Name,null,DB_Version);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        databaseQuery.onCreate(database);
      }
    public static class databaseQuery 
    {
        public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)
        {   
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+tbl_arrival1);
            database.execSQL(STRING_CREATE1);
        }
    }
}
```

I use this database helper in content provider :

```
database1 DBHelper ;
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) 
    {
        long row_id;
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        row_id=sqlDB.insert(tbl_arrival1, null, values);
        if(row_id>0)
        {
            Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, row_id);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
            return _uri;
        }
        throw new SQLException("Failed to insert into "+uri);
    }
```

The problem is that, the query drop table, is not working!

All suggestion and answer would be highly appreciated...

thanks

Comment: Have you tried called drop table in OnUpdate method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreate` will work only once at time of creation once the database is created you should make use of `onUpgrade()` to drop table if any changes has been made to old version

**EDIT**
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: can you give me tutorial link about using onUpgrade() ! I've never try with it.. thanks

Comment: does not work for me, I tried to drop tables in onUpgrade(), but there was no result, Tables stayed with old data. I checked it by placing break point right after sqlExec() method, then copied database file to my computer and open it in sqlite viewer program. Most of all, I tried to execute same sql queries on same database, and it worked !

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm bit late but this question was relevant for me. In my case I tried to drop many tables in single a query, i. e.

```
drop table if exists table_name1;
drop table if exists table_name2;
drop table if exists table_name3;
```

so android's implementation of `execSQL()` executes only **single** sql statement

Comment: My hero! I've been searching for a reason my queries wouldn't execute, finally, someone with an answer. You'd think they'd let execSQL throw an exception or something for more than one query.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be fine. You are calling DROP TABLE and then creating again subsequently. How you checked the DROP TABLE is not working?

Comment: The table is still exist with the old data